# Access docker-machine VM ports without port forwarding

Tags: docker, portforwarding, docker-machine

I'm trying to learn Docker and so far I have run into a lot of "work arounds" that are needed in docker-machine but not in boot2docker.

My current issue is accessing my docker containers from my host.

I have my Windows host, running a VM created with docker-machine, and inside that docker VM I'm running a simple nginx server container.

The nginx container is ran to expose it's 80 port to the docker-machine's 8000.

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 nginx
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is being able to open this server from my Windows using a browser.

If I in Windows use curl (Git bash, not ssh-ed into the docker-machine VM) using the IP that docker-machine ip gives me, then it works. But using my browser doesn't (I'm using Microsoft Edge currently), I can get the browser to work if I set up a NAT port forwarding.

```
curl $(docker-machine ip dev):8000
```

As I've read it should be possible to access the VM ports without specifying port forwarding rules for every port, that VirtualBox should expose and forward those automatically.

What am I doing wrong or do I have to specify port forwarding rules for every port between my VM and host OS that I want to use?

Comment: Do you mean that http://<the ip returned by docker-machine ip dev>:8000/ does not work?

Comment: Yes, but only when trying to use my browser. Since it's a web server I'm not looking to use curl all the time!

Answer (score 2):

After another day of digging I had the wild and crazy idea to try another browser and it works fine.

So for anyone running into this issue and you're using Microsoft Edge (to try it out like me), switch browser. Chrome and even old IE works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, `$(docker-machine ip dev)` means "run the command `docker-machine ip dev`, take the output of that command and insert it into the command-line here".

If you run

```
docker-machine ip dev
```

in your shell, it will print an IP address which you can use in your web browser.

If you put this address in `/etc/hosts` (or your platform's analog) you can use a friendly alias for the IP address.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get the IP of my docker-machine (the docker host) but putting that IP into the browser doesn't work (unless I have a port forwarding setup on the NAT of the docker-machine). I've found something like Docker Bridged mode that I will try and see if that does what I want (i.e. avoiding the need to specify all port forwarding ports manually).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because my browser was configured with a [proxy pac (Proxy_auto-config file)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) which did not include 192.169.x.y internal boot2docker machines ips.

That means:

- the browser tries to contact the enterprise proxy (and that fails),
- while a regular `CMD` shell session, with a `NO_PROXY` environment variable set to `192.168.x.y`, would allow a `curl http://192.168.x.y/...` to work without a glitch.